# Out-of-bounds run-time error thrown relative to constructor

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, runtime-error

I immediately get a run-time error originating in my `Student` class constructor. This is the only error I am **aware** of, however, there may be more.

Error reads as follows:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>
> > at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
> >
> > at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:426)
> >
> > at Student.(Student.java:11)
> >
> > at TestStudent.main(TestStudent.java:5)

A graphic showing the error in my IDE:

[image: run-time error]

**This is the updated and functioning code:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Integer> quizList = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
    public Student(String name, int qz1, int qz2, int qz3, int qz4, int qz5) {
        this.name = name;
        int qz[] = {qz1, qz2, qz3, qz4, qz5};
        for(int i = 0; i < qz.length; i++) {
            quizList.add(qz[i]);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        return this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getQuizList() {
        return quizList;
    }

    public int getQuiz(int location) {
        return quizList.get(location);
    }

    public void setQuiz(int location, int qz) {
        quizList.set(location, qz);
    }
}

import java.util.*;
public class TestStudent {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("Mark Kennedy", 70, 80, 90, 100, 90));
        list.add(new Student("Max Gerard", 80, 85, 90, 85, 80));
        list.add(new Student("Jean Smith", 50, 79, 89, 99, 100));
        list.add(new Student("Betty Farm", 85, 80, 85, 88, 89));
        list.add(new Student("Dilbert Gamme", 70, 70, 90, 70, 80));

        printBook(list);
    }

    public static void printBook(ArrayList<Student> list) {
        for(Student token : list) {
            System.out.print(token.getName() + "\t");
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%5d\t", token.getQuiz(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void replaceName(ArrayList<Student> list, String find, String replace) {
        int position = 0;
        int values[] = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            values[i] = list.get(i).getQuiz(i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getName().equals(find)) {
                list.get(i).setName(replace);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void replaceQuiz(ArrayList<Student> list, String find, int quizNum, int replace) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getName().equals(find)) {
               list.get(i).setQuiz((quizNum-1), replace);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void replaceStudent(ArrayList<Student> list, String find, Student replacement) {
        insertStudent(list, find, replacement.getName());
        deleteStudent(list, find);
    }

    public static void insertStudent(ArrayList<Student> list, String find, String name) {
        int position = 0;
        int values[] = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            values[i] = list.get(i).getQuiz(i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).getName().equals(find)) {
                position = i;
            }
        }
        list.add(position, new Student(name, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]));
    }

    public static void deleteStudent(ArrayList<Student> list, String find) {
        int location = 0;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getName().equals(find)) {
                location = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i != list.size()) {
            list.remove(location);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Modified a bit of code in `Student`:

```
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Integer> quizList;
    public Student(String name, int qz1, int qz2, int qz3, int qz4, int qz5) {
        this.name = name;
        int qz[] = {qz1, qz2, qz3, qz4, qz5};
        for(int i = 0; i < qz.length; i++) {
            quizList.add(qz[i]);
        }
    }
```

This error is now thrown:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> > at Student.(Student.java:9)
> >
> > at TestStudent.main(TestStudent.java:5)

[image: Updated error]

Comment: You can save only the objects to an arraylist, not the primittive data type values

Comment: @RajeshKumar Autoboxing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `quizList.add(qz[i]);` instead of `quizList.set(i, qz[i]);` Your List is empty at the point where you want to set an Object to a specific position.

[documentation of set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29):

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

to your update:

you removed the line `quizList = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);`. It initializes your list. You need to ceep this line in place, otherwise there is no list you can add your objects to. A `NullPointerException` always means an Objects was not created wile you want to read from/write to it.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException

at Student.<init>(Student.java:10)

at TestStudent.main(TestStudent.java:5)`

Comment: Any idea what's causing this NullPointerException?

Comment: @alx: see my update. you need to ceep this line `quizList = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);` in place.

Comment: Thanks man--appreciate the help and friendliness. At least some community members like to help, and don't down-vote people for being less-experienced.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<>(int i)` does *not* make your `ArrayList` have an initial size of `i` the same way that `int[5]` makes the array have an initial length of `i`. What it does is initializes the size of the *internal backing array* to `i`, while leaving the actual `ArrayList` completely empty. For all intents and purposes, your `ArrayList` is an empty array with no elements.

So when you try to set any of the elements in the `ArrayList` to something else, there's the minor problem that *there's nothing to set*, because *there's nothing in there*.

You're going to have to add elements to the `ArrayList` before you can change elements in there to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList constructor with an int specifies initial capacity, not size. The size is still zero, since there are no elements in the arraylist. This is why the set method fails, as it checks the size first. Why don't you just use add() instead?

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int), E)